# Add Over Saturation Effect on AVCaptureDevice in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cifilter, avcapturedevice

I have implemented custom camera into my app. So, I am creating this camera using `AVCaptureDevice`. Also I have set GrayScale on this custom camera using [Set GrayScale on Output of AVCaptureDevice in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38122040/3908884) this.

Now I want to add over saturation effect on camera. "Oversaturation hint" should be calculated according to formula provided. (convert overexposure pixel (R,G,B >= 255) to yellow (RGB 255,255,0)).

I want exact effect which is showing in following Image.

[image]

I am creating GrayScale using following code:-

```
let sepiaColor = CIColor(
    red: 1.0 / 0.30078125,
    green: 1.0 / 0.5859375,
    blue: 1.0 / 0.11328125
)

filter = CIFilter(
    name: "CIColorMonochrome",
    withInputParameters: [
        "inputColor" : sepiaColor,
        "inputIntensity" : 1.0
    ]
)
```

How can I create this over saturation effect using `CIFilter`.? I have reviewed [Core Image Filter Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html) document for `CIFilter`. But didn’t get idea about How to create this effect using this. May be 
`CIColorCrossPolynomial` or `CIColorMap` are working for this.

Is there any way to create this effect on `AVCaptureDevice`.?

Any Help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: I would create my own filter. You can follow these steps to do so: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html

Comment: This WWDC explains how to do that: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/514/

Comment: Thanks @KunalShrivastava.  Please provide any sample code for this. So it's good me.

Comment: When you say "convert overexposure pixel (R,G,B >= 255) to yellow (RGB 255,255,0)", do you mean converting the pixels whose (R+G+B) valus is greater than or equal to than 255?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic/algorithm:

> (convert overexposure pixel (R,G,B >= 255) to yellow (RGB 255,255,0))

will go in the kernel, which is essentially the computation you want to perform on each pixel.

Here's a simple filter I have written. In the if condition of the kernel, write your own condition. The *then* part already converts the pixel into (255, 255, 0).

**.h**

```
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

@interface CustomFilter : CIFilter

@property(nonatomic, retain) CIImage *inputImage;

-(CIImage*)outputImage;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "CustomFilter.h"

@implementation CustomFilter

-(CIColorKernel*)myKernel
{
    static CIColorKernel *kernel = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        kernel = [CIColorKernel kernelWithString:
                  @"kernel vec4 CustomFilter ( __sample s ) \n { \n if ( s.r + s.g + s.b < 0.1 ) \n { return s.rgba = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); } \n else \n { return s.rgba; } \n }"];
    });

    return kernel;
}

-(CIImage*)outputImage
{
    CGRect dod = _inputImage.extent;
    return [[self myKernel] applyWithExtent:dod arguments:@[_inputImage]];
}

@end
```

Comment: Great @kunal. It works. Thanks. I am using this condition s.r + s.g + s.b >= 1.0 instead of yours. Thank you again.